# How to get only arrays or another type from interface?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface like that:

```
interface Car {
  model: string;
  owners: string[];
}
```

And I want to get only array properties:

```
type NewCar = OnlyArrays<Car>
```

And this will be equal to:

```
type NewCar = {
  owners: string[];
}
```

Type it's not important, array just for example.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
function getCar<T = Car>(id: string): { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends array ? string[] : string; };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a mapped type and remap the keys ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)) to include only those keys for which the value extends an array:

```
type OnlyArrays<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Array<infer _> ? K : never]: T[K]
}

type NewCar = OnlyArrays<Car>
// type NewCar = { owners: string[] }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=30#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgWwHsATCAGwC5kBnMKUAcwG49kiB3EaG6uhkIwDaAXVYBfHDjABPAA4oA8iHIyAglChwZNADwAVAHzIAvNjZCA0slDIA1hBlEYyfcjg1XVkcggAPSBASTw0tGV1QGGhkAH1jAH5ka2puADdoEWp9bxxJaXkUADkIDnRMM2VVUO09MsMcAHoG-GQAPXicIA)

Comment: Thank you, it's working for me but I rewrite to return type and this is my case `[P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer _> ? string[] : string;`